# Shine/Sheen effect on hover for SVG?

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate

I'm new to SVG animation and I was hoping someone could help me achieve an effect.

I have two questions actually:
1.) As you can see in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/pen/bEwqzM). I have an CSS keyframe animation that draws out a shape, fill a flat color then ends in a SVG gradient.  However it doesn't properly transition to that gradient (it just kinda 'pops' to that state at the end)

CSS Animation

```
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
   0% {stroke-dashoffset: 900; fill:#FFF;}
   85% {stroke-dashoffset: 0; fill:#FFF;}
  90% {fill:#fce669;}
  100% {fill:url(#glow);}
}
```

SVG '#Glow' gradient

```
  <defs>
        <linearGradient id = "glow" x1 = "0%" y1 = "0%" x2 = "100%" y2 = "100%">
            <stop stop-color = "#fce669" offset = "0%"/>
            <stop stop-color = "#fff" offset = "100%"/>
        </linearGradient>
  </defs>
```

Is it possible to transition between these states?

Okay that aside, here's my real question:

2.) Ideally, after the drawing animation is complete, I'd like there to be a sheen effect that is also triggered on hover. Like [this codepen](http://codepen.io/iamvdo/pen/maJhu). I tried animating the color stops on the gradient to achieve this effect and it's pretty terrible.
http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/pen/eJdWeJ

I really have no idea how to proceed with this.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to came in some hard place here...

I am not sure about the specs recommendations for this, but from tests, it seems that svg's `linearGradient` can't be animated through CSS. I guess that it's because it is seen as an image, just like CSS gradients are seen as `background-image`.

Note that Firefox won't even execute the animation if you place a `<funcIRI>` into it (`url(#yourElement)`). Once again, I couldn't find the specs about this, so can't tell for sure if that's a bug, but since Chrome is deprecating SMIL, that will probably become an issue quite soon.

But for today, the only workaround I can give you, is to use SMIL.

You can use `<animate>` elements to animate your `linearGradient`. In the example above, I do animate only one `stop-color` of the `#glow` gradient.

I also used an other animated linear-gradient to the shine effect. This linear-gradient is then applied as the `fill` attribute of a mask, making the black part of the gradient the only masking of the `<mask>` element.
Note that chrome only do render offset's animation if you do use absolute `values`...

```css
svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.st0 {
  stroke-dasharray: 900;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: url(#glow);
  animation: dash 4s linear alternate;
  -webkit-animation: dash 4s linear alternate;
}
@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 900;
  }
  85% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 900;
  }
  85% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
.st2 {
  fill: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="starmoon" class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 254.7 220.8" style="enable-background:new 0 0 254.7 220.8;" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
      stroke: #EFA441;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }
  </style>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="glow" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
      <stop stop-color="#FFF" offset="0%">
        <animate id="color" attributeName="stop-color" from="#fff" to="#fce669" dur="0.8s" begin="3.2s" fill="freeze" />
      </stop>
      <stop stop-color="#fff" offset="100%" />
    </linearGradient>

    <!-- the gradient used by the mask -->
    <linearGradient id="shine" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
      <stop stop-color="white" offset="-10%">
        <animate attributeName="offset" values="-.05;.95" dur="2s" begin="color.end" />
      </stop>
      <stop stop-color="black" offset="-5%">
        <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;1" dur="2s" begin="color.end" />
      </stop>
      <stop stop-color="white" offset="0%">
        <animate attributeName="offset" values=".05;1.05" dur="2s" begin="color.end" />
      </stop>
    </linearGradient>


    <mask id="myShiningMask">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#shine)" />
    </mask>

  </defs>
  <path fill="url(#glow)" class="st0 icon" d="M169,69.1l5.4-5.4c1.6-1.6,0.8-4.3-1.5-4.7l-42.6-7.6c-0.9-0.2-1.6-0.7-2-1.5l-19.7-38.4c-1-2-3.9-2-5,0
 L83.5,49.4c-0.4,0.8-1.2,1.3-2,1.4l-42.7,6.5c-2.2,0.3-3.2,3.1-1.6,4.7L67.3,93c0.6,0.6,0.9,1.5,0.8,2.4l-6.7,42.3
 c-0.4,2.2,1.9,3.9,4,3l38.9-18.7c0.8-0.4,1.7-0.4,2.5,0l38.6,19.7c2,1,4.4-0.6,4-2.9l-6.1-42.5c-0.1-0.9,0.2-1.8,0.8-2.4l15.2-15
 c10,9.6,16.2,23.1,16.2,38.1c0,29.3-23.7,53-53,53c-10,0-19.3-2.8-27.3-7.6c10.8,21.4,33,36.1,58.6,36.1c36.2,0,65.6-29.4,65.6-65.6
 C219.1,102,197.7,76.1,169,69.1z" mask="url(#myShiningMask)" />

  <circle class="st2" cx="87.9" cy="67.3" r="12.4" fill="white" />

</svg>
```

Comment: Wow! That looks fantastic! Thank you so much.  I need to read it over more thoroughly when it's not the wee hours of the morning but I just wanted to say thank you before I went to bed.  Yeah, I have to say starting out in SVG is kinda rough... Hopefully there'll be better implementation and documentation in the future :/ Anyway, you made my night! Now I just gotta figure out the hover part. I hope I can make something cool! Thanks again. :D

Comment: You're welcome ! For the hover, you could just change the `begin` attributes in the mask gradient from `begin="color.end"` to `begin="color.end; star.mouseover"` where `star` would be the id of your `<path>` element. This way, the `myShiningMask`'s animation will restart every time you hover over the path.

Comment: Haha you just saved me a lot of time! I was thinking I needed to add a class with javascript or something... Blah, I really don't have a good sense of how to do things with SVG.  I guess I need to have the star logo in white underneath if I have a BG that isn't white for the sheen effect to look nice.  Thank you again for sharing your expertise.